# Use jQuery to set several default dropdown values without using element ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, google-chrome-extension

I'm inputting a whole lot of data into a company's internal systems - there's a form entry page with a few dropdown boxes where I'm constantly selecting the same values over and over. For reasons beyond my understanding, these dropdown fields don't have IDs - just a common CSS class. I haven't dug into the (surprisingly complex) HTML so I'm not sure why they've done it this way, but I guess that's the constraint I've got to work to. I'm trying to make my life a little easier with a Chrome plugin that will set defaults on the form in question.

Here's a sample of one of the combo boxes:

```
<select class="gwt-ListBox"><option value="">Select...</option><option value="ar">Arabic</option><option value="bg">Bulgarian</option><option value="ca">Catalan</option><option value="zh_CN">Chinese (simplified)</option></select>
```

There are several more on the page, all with  and no ID.

I think what I'd like to do is move through the dropdowns on the page by some kind of field index number and set default values accordingly. Is this possible? Could someone provide some rough code for one or two and I'll extrapolate from there? Not great with jQuery so I hugely appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: welcome unknown user , you may want to try to to develop this then post when what you have thats not working and we can help you better understand your code

Comment: refine your post my friend. as you do, i have one question - can you not simply add an ID to these elements? it would be a safe thing to do and make your jquery stuff a LOT easier to write. and you could keep it in page rather than build a browser plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should set the first option in each dropdown to selected:

```
$('select > option:first').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Edit:
I meant "first", not "first-child".

Answer (score 0):

You can select all "select" fields on page by `$("select")` and you will get an array of DOM objects to control. To get fields in one form you can try to `$("select", "form_or_div")` where you want to get them. The third way is to get `$("form")[0].elements` this will give you all elements in first form that would find jquery selector, by changing key in this array you  can go over all forms on page.

In simple just get an jquery

```
$("select").each(function(i, item){
  console.log(i, item);
});
```

And if you know that the number of element is not changing you can operate by it.